# How can I create CSR and corresponding key with vanilla Powershell (and no other software)?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, pki, windows-server-2016

I need to automatically generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) and the corresponding private key as two separate files.

The files are to be used by some software application and they need to be in PEM format (base64). I have no way to get around this.

I'm working on Windows Server 2016 Core, and I cannot install any extra tools. If I could, I would install OpenSSL. All I have is PowerShell.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Answer: probably?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'certreq.exe' utility:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks. But what flags should I use? I don't see anything regarding getting the key for a request.